# Local Group Policy IE9

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, internet-explorer-9

I have this weird issue on Windows 7 64bit desktop, I am trying to lock it down from Internet usage (it's a stand alone machine with several local users), so I use local GP.  Well, I enabled the policy [image: [click here to see]]

But it's still goes to auto detection [image: [click here to see]]

I am not really sure how to fix the issue.  Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1.II.2013 10.48**

I also should mention, I did run **gpudate /force** and it was successful each time.

Comment: The "Automatically detect settings" option is controlled by the GPO setting directly above the one you're showing in your screenshot.

Comment: @joeqwerty That should be controlled by that, but it is not.  I can still go to any website (I know it's not shown on the screenshot, but we have about 5 exceptions).

Comment: I didn't say that the setting would resolve the issue, I was merely pointing out that the "Automatically detect settings" GPO setting was above the setting you originally showed. Now, getting it working the way you want is another matter.

Comment: Why are you trying to do it this way? Do you have a proxy server in place?

Comment: @JohnThePro The idea here is to let users have limited web access and only to approved websites

Comment: Then I really would recommend not using Group Policy to accomplish this. There are better solutions for this. Take a look at my answer, and I'll elaborate more if you need me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at this article here. It basically gives you a step by step on how to accomplish what you're trying to do, in the way you're trying to do it.

http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/07/how-to-use-group-policy-to-allow-or-block-urls/

Me personally, I would either install a program that runs as a service that you can use to restrict internet access, or use a service like OpenDNS to filter your internet traffic as well (or both!). There are free options for both, without having to use group policy.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)